# Redirecting R help message to a text file

Tags: r

I have R installed on Linux. To get instant help I type on the prompt as:

```
?read.table
```

Is it possible to redirect this help message to a text file. For example, if I want Linux man page to be redirected to a text file, I write on the shell as:

```
$ man cp | col -b > cp_help.txt
```

Such text file is of great help as I can search within it, or scroll fast up and down or add my comments/examples for future or distribute to students.

Comment: Not an answer, but a clarification: What about viewing the help in a browser? Does that meet your needs?

Comment: I can view the help in the browser using 'options(help_type = "html")' but redirecting it to a text will help me to add my own examples/comments and also preserve proper formatting and alignments. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Josh O'Brien. Sorry for trouble with so many editing corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R offers the tool `Rscript` to run R code from the console. You can pass a script as argument

```
Rscript myScript.R
```

but you can also directly enter an R command using the option `-e`. Now it is easy to redirect the help into a file

```
Rscript -e "?read.table" | col -b > read.table.txt
```

Comment: What an answer! And the way to get the result! Brilliant.